# AWS tools with two accounts, not recognising second account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've downloaded the AWS cli tools. I have two separate AWS accounts. Everything worked as expected for the first account. But I cannot seem to switch the tools over to the second account. Every time I run ec2-describe-instances it lists the instances of my first account not my second. Here are the environment variables I have reset:

in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export EC2_CERT=/path/to/cert
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/path/to/key
export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=/path/to/file/with/access/and/private/key
```

I then ran "source ~/.bash_profile" and also echoed out the above env vars to double check that they had been set. What am I missing?